# Copy a folder with Smartsheet API - Java SDK 2.0.5

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

I am trying to copy a folder with the Smartsheet API 2.0 (Java SDK 2.0.5).
Unfortunately the folders and sheets (all sub folders/sheets too) are copied but the sheet data is missing.

I get no errors everything works fine.
I tried several variants of the optional include parameters the ".ALL", "null", ...

This is the example code and the used environment:

- Netbeans IDE 8.2
- smartsheet-sdk-java-2.0.5.jar (with maven)

```
// Optional params
EnumSet includes = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(FolderCopyInclusion.ALL)); // Copy all fields!
EnumSet skipRemap = EnumSet.noneOf(FolderRemapExclusion.class); // Remap all fields

// Specify destination.
ContainerDestination destination = new ContainerDestination.AddContainerDestinationBuilder()
        .setDestinationType(DestinationType.FOLDER)
        .setDestinationId(targetFolder.getId())
        .setNewName(folder.getName())
        .build();

smartsheet.folderResources().copyFolder(folder.getId(), destination, includes, skipRemap);
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing this line:

```
EnumSet includes = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(FolderCopyInclusion.ALL)); // Copy all fields!
```

To this instead:

```
EnumSet includes = EnumSet.of(FolderCopyInclusion.ALL);
```

(I'm not a Java expert, but the change I've suggested is consistent with the code example in the [Smartsheet API Documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#copy-folder).)

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work too. I will loop the directories and copy/create all the elements at a single level. Thanks for your help.